# SpriteKit find point on perimeter of screen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cgrect

I need to find a generate a random point just outside the screen to spawn an enemy. How can I do this? I looked up other topics on this but they were all confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method like this :

```
+(CGPoint)randomPointInRects:(NSArray*)rects
{
    // choose one of the rects in the array randomly 
    int randomIndex = arc4random() % rects.count;
    CGRect rect = [(NSValue*)rects[randomIndex] CGRectValue];

    // get a random x and y location based on the chosen rect
    float randX = arc4random() % (int)rect.size.width + rect.origin.x;
    float randY = arc4random() % (int)rect.size.height + rect.origin.y;

    // store value in point
    CGPoint randomPoint = CGPointMake(randX, randY);

    return randomPoint;
}
```

Then to get that random point on say a 1024x768 screen you might do something like this :

```
    NSMutableArray *rects = [NSMutableArray array];

    // define spawn areas with CGRect's

    //top
    [rects addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 768, 1024, 50)]];

    // bottom
    [rects addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, -50, 1024, 50)]];

    //left
    [rects addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(-50, 0, 50, 768)]];

    //right
    [rects addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(1024, 0, 50, 768)]];

    // pass array to method to return a random point in those rects.
    CGPoint randomPoint = [self randomPointInRects:rects];
```

You basically define the areas you want to have nodes spawned, store them in an array, pass them to the method and it will return a random point from those rects.

I added a 50 pixel buffer for each edge.

I did this quickly, so it might have a bug, but the logic of the approach should get you there if so! :)

This solution would also work for any situation where you wanted to have something spawned in multiple areas, defined by `CGRect`s.